# How do I make a responsive navigation menu?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7ayE5AtRUA) and I can't get the navigation menu to work. [I have also watched this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAVQh2gfIfc) where the tutor states that by changing the position to static, one can make it responsive and look neat on a mobile device. I am trying to move my submenu more to the right and have it changed back into position absolute of around 150px but my game menu does not work too well...

I also noticed that if I changed the left position to around 200px, then it does work better but this is too far to the left:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: verdana;
    background-color: #abc;
    padding: 50px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Rules for navigation menu */

ul#navmenu, ul.sub1  , ul.sub2 {
    list-style: none;

    font-size: 12px;
}

ul#navmenu li {

    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; /*This is very important to get sub menu absolutely line up with it */
    float: left; /*Get elements side by side */
    margin-right: 4px;

}

ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}



ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {       /* > child selector */
    background-color: #cfc;

}

ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color: #ff0;
}


ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
}

ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 251px;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
}

ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display:block;
}

.darrow {
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 4px;
}

.rarrow {
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 4px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul#navmenu li {

    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; /*This is very important to get sub menu absolutely line up with it */
    float: center; 
    margin-right: 4px;

}

ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}



ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 5px;

}

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 10px;
}





ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: -50px;


}



ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: static;


}

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
}

ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display:block;
}
.darrow {
    display: none;
}

.rarrow {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Good to hear that you worked on it and need some assistance but without HTML code only you could understand what is going on. So edit your code and post HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> how to do a responsive navigation menu

Try the following. It makes use of only HTML and CSS.

```css
body { 
  background: #ccc;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

/* a little "umph" */
.decor {
  background: #6EAF8D;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #CDEBDB 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #CDEBDB 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #CDEBDB 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, white 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background-size: 50px 25%;;
  padding: 2px;
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

/* clear'n floats */
ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

ul:before,
ul:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #0E0E0E;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

/* prime */
ul.primary li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid #3D3D3D;
}

ul.primary li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
}

ul.primary li a:hover {
  
  color: #000;
}

/* subs */
ul.sub {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #BEBEBE;
  width: 35%;
  display:none;
}

ul.sub li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.sub li a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

ul.sub li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.sub li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

/* sub display*/
ul.primary li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

/* keeps the tab background white */
ul.primary li:hover a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: none;
}

ul.primary li:hover > a{
  color: #000;
} 

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .decor {
    padding: 3px;
  }
  
  .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
   li {
    float: none;
  }
  
  ul.primary li:hover a {
    background: none;
    color: #8B8B8B;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  }

  ul.primary li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    background: #272727;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  ul.sub {
    display: block;  
    position: static;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  ul.sub li a {
    background: #272727;
   border: none;
    color: #8B8B8B;
  }
  
  ul.sub li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<div class="wrap">
<span class="decor"></span>
<nav>
  <ul class="primary">
    <li>
      <a href="">Dog</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Bulldog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Mastiff</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Labrador</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Mutt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Cat</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Tabby</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Black Cat</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Wrinkly Cat</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Bird</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Humming Bird</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hawk</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Crow</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Horse</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Brown Horse</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Race Horse</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tall Horse</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Burger</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Cheesy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">More Ketchup</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Some Mustard</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Extra Butter</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping that you could try to follow the video as that would assist in my learning...

Comment: I read from this site that you have to add separate queries for landscape and portrait orientation... is this correct

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/#galaxy-phone-queries